# How to override a git log pretty format?

Tags: git, git-log

The available built-in pretty formats don't exactly fit my need (or my taste):

https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

`git log --decorate --graph --all --pretty=short` is almost what I want, but I'd like the commit date to be shown as well...

`git log --decorate --graph --all --pretty=medium` is nice, but I don't want to the full commit message. I'd like only the first line of the commit message to be shown...

---

So I tried to define my own pretty format, just like 'medium' but without the full commit message, like so:

```
git log --decorate --graph --all --pretty=format:'commit %H%nAuthor: %an%nDate: %ad%n%n%s%n'
```

One problem is the branch names are not shown anymore. Another problem is the logs are not in color anymore. How can I do that correctly?

Ideally, I'd just like to *override* `--pretty=medium` so that it will not show the full commit message, but only the title of the commit (or to *override* `--pretty=short` for it to show the date). Is this only possible (to *override* a built-in pretty format)? If yes, how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--decorate` does not work with an own format. If you want it, you need to use `%d` or `%D`. And if you like you can also add some coloring to get similar output like for medium you probably want something like:

```
git log --graph --all --pretty=format:'%C(auto,yellow)commit %H%C(auto,green bold)%d%Creset%nAuthor: %an%nDate: %ad%n%n%s%n'
```

Comment: Could be even closer to the builtin `--decorate` if there were distinct colors for HEAD,  -> <branch_name>, and <remote branch>. Almost perfect match! Best answer so far. Thanks. +1

Comment: Yep, but I didn't find a token for colorized decorate stuff, so you can only do it en bloc.